# How to retrieve any API Key in Google App Engine by Java, Python, PHP, and Go

Tags: google-app-engine, key, credentials

I am using GAE to build an application. I have enable some API's & obtain the keys on the Credentials Menu that I need to put so my application can work on private or public access.

Is there any method or a Function or a Libraries in Java, Python, PHP, and Go to retrieve those keys and store it in a variable? I could not find this in the [GAE Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs) or [General Question](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/general#https).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hard set answer for this. I would read these

[GAE: best practices for storing secret keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501234/gae-best-practices-for-storing-secret-keys) Read both answers not just the accepted one.

[Client Secrets File](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets)

[Best practices for securely using API keys](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#apikeybestpractices)

To do the actual OAuth I would recommend [decorators](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#Decorators)

Comment: I have came before to the documentation you mentioned. As far as I could understand those documentation are explaining how to 'store'. My question is asking how to 'retrieve' for storing in a variables i.e. $x = Retrieve_function(y); //x = the keys

Comment: Look at the link for decorators, scroll down to where it says OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets (talks about oauth_aware) on how to use it. If you just want to get it into a variable you can open the file and read the contents. Its a json file, so the python json reader would work.