# How to set env var?

Tags: google-app-engine, environment-variables

Where can I write `critical` environment variables like on heroku?
I do not want to store the keys of my database in clear in app.yaml file.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach to store secrets in GCP is using [Cloud Key Management Service](https://cloud.google.com/kms/) and Cloud Storage.

The [Storing Secrets documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/store-secrets) guides you through the process of storing a secret in Cloud Storage bucket encrypted at the application layer with Cloud KMS. There's also other ways to manage secrets with Cloud KMS, it's documented in the [Secret management with Cloud KMS page](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/secret-management)